# How can i post videos on api, my case Dood stream using python?

Tags: python, api, python-requests

I am new in programming and i searched may resources for this questions.

In this case in this case  i am using [Dood stream](https://doodstream.com/videos). I have the api Doc in Crul only. I tried different things but i am unable to post it.

[•Dood stream api doc](https://doodstream.com/api-docs)

Image of upload doc:

Thing that i tried:

```
import requests
with open(r'Test.mp4', 'rb') as finput:
   response = requests.put('https://doodapi.com/api/upload/server?key=xxx', data=finput)
   print(response)
   
   
import requests
url = "https://xxx.dood.video/upload/01?57471j16x5bruvmgxasl6"


data = {'title':'metadata','timeDuration':120}
mp3_f = open('Test.mp4', 'rb')
files = {'messageFile': mp3_f}

req = requests.post(url, files=mp3_f)
print (req.status_code)
print (req.content)
```

Please consider helping!!

Comment: https://curlconverter.com/

Comment: did you use a real API key?